# How to guarantee listeners are called in the same order that data is added to a StreamController

Tags: dart, stream

When I run the code below I expected to see:

Stream 1 says: true
Stream 1 says: false
Stream 2 says: true

because this is the order that data was added to the `StreamController`s.

but instead, I see:

Stream 1 says: true
Stream 2 says: true
Stream 1 says: false

```dart
import 'dart:async';
void main() {
  StreamController<bool> streamController1 = StreamController();
  StreamController<bool> streamController2 = StreamController();
  
    
  void _handleStream1(bool thing){
    print("Stream 1 says: " + thing.toString());
  }
  
  void _handleStream2(bool thing){
    print("Stream 2 says: " + thing.toString());
  }
  
  streamController1.stream.listen(_handleStream1);
  streamController2.stream.listen(_handleStream2);
  
  streamController1.sink.add(true);
  streamController1.sink.add(false);
  
  streamController2.sink.add(true);
}
```

1. Why is this the case?
2. How would I make sure that the execution order is maintained?

I figured that if data is added to streams in the same isolate in dart then listeners would be called FIFO style but I might be missing something fundamental!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this ended up being a "fun" adventure in the internal of the Dart code base. In short, what I think really happens here are:

1. You are adding elements to both sinks.
2. When adding the first item to a `Sink` (from `StreamController`), Dart will schedule a microtask behind the scene. But this will only happen if there are not already scheduled a task for this `Sink`.
3. The first microtask (from `streamController1`) are running and will handle ONE value. After this event has been executed, it will check if there are more event to be handled. If that is the case, it will schedule a new microtask.
4. Next microtask is handled which are going to be from `streamController2` and we are handling this value. Since there are no more values for this `StreamController`, we are not scheduling another microtask.
5. We are going to handle the last microtask (the one spawned from step 3) to handle the last value in `streamController1`.

I have not found any indication of the reason for this design but if I should come with a guess, I think this has been done so you don't end up with a scenario where a single `StreamController` takes priority without making room for other `StreamController` instances.

This is okay since we should not expect the other of executed events to be in any specific order across separated instances of `StreamController`. If the order is important, you should put the code inside your first `listen` or spawn the new event here if it is dependent on execution of the first handler.

*Note:* I cannot give a easy explanation to how I did found out the details since the architecture looks to be much inspired by the spaghetti monster (I am very sure there are logic behind everything). But you can search around in the following links:

- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/2.10.1/sdk/lib/async/stream_controller.dart
- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/2.10.1/sdk/lib/async/stream_impl.dart

Comment: Wow - nice investigation! As you recommended - I'll just deal with the order not being guaranteed. Thanks for the deep dive